# Is there a timer function for C# win form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a timer function to my browser project, which should be able to be edited to preferred duration or turned off, so after the timer is reached the form is closed or locked by password protection. Therefore, my question is that is there any built functions within forms which allows you to do this, if not is there any supporting functions. any tips/examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean like a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: In search box of Toolbox search for Timer

Comment: in your question you write about a browser project. how does this relate to your tags "winforms"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer class should be able to do what you need. Also see the documentation here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //calculate your time and perform whatever action here
    }
}
```

Comment: That Timer should be declared at the Form scope so that it can be disposed of when the form closes.